# Insert checkbox data from html form to sql using java

Tags: java, mysql, forms, servlets

I've a simple form which takes the **StudentId** as *text* and choice of favourite **Cars** using *checkboxes* in HTML.

Now, I want to create a *servlet* in Java, which takes values from this form and store in the MySql database.

```
<form action="/servlet">
    <label>Student Id : </label><input type="text" name"sid"></br>
    <label>Cars : </label></br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cars" value="BMW">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cars" value="Mercedes">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cars" value="Hyundai">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cars" value="Toyota">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The point where I'm confused is that how to insert the data of this checkbox "**Cars**" in MySql?

I can get the array in a variable

```
String[] cars = request.getPrameterValues("cars");
```

But how this array can be stored in the column named **cars** in MySql.

> This thing is easily achieved in No-Sql

At First, I thought to make a single string of comma-separated values and simply store it in the column, but at the time of retrieval, this will be a lot of code. So, I wondered if there is some other better way to achieve this.

Comment: first learn about sql and normalization. then create your tables, then you'll know how to insert each car into your table as a separate record. The insert part it simple once your tables are created.

Comment: @issac Do I need to create another table for Cars and use join at the time of retrieval?

Comment: hint - learn about `1 to many` relationship and `many to many` relationships.

Answer (score 1):

I seems your logic is not correct, why?

Generally this datas should be stored in database, then to show them, you call your table and show the result in HTML. But in your case, you code the IHM and you want to fill the database, and this is not correct.

So to solve the issue, create a table in your database named car or model, fill it with the different information, each car should be in a raw. and don't manipulate cars with arrays in database, it is not a good practice.

Comment: so, how the checkboxes are dealt in databases?

Comment: @Genius get information from database, store all the info in a list of objects, then fill the checkboxes

Comment: Yes, I got that, but my doubt here is - how the check boxes stored in database, what is the datatype used while creating table?

Comment: don't store the checkboxes but store the value which should be `BMW`, `Mercedes` ..

Comment: You mean boolean?

Comment: Can you write a query for it, suppose I got the array of cars using `String[] cars = request.getPrameterValues("cars");`  Now, what is the query to store data the way you suggest?

Comment: there are a big work behind, you have to create the table, then fill the table, then get the info from database then fill the checkboxes